# pod 'Bolts' getting an error when i tried pod install command

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, git, cocoapods

I pulled latest code from develop branch that contains pod’Bolts’ in podfile.After that i tried pod install command in terminal,then i got the following error in my terminal

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `Bolts` required by `Podfile`
> - `Bolts` required by `Podfile`
> - `Bolts (= 1.8.4)` required by `Podfile.lock`
>
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies:
>   `Bolts, Bolts (= 1.8.4)`.
>
> You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with
>   `pod repo update`.  * mistyped the name or version.  * not added the
>   source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
>
> Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod
>   install` by default.

My podfile looking like this

```
use_frameworks!

def pods
    pod 'Bolts'
end

target 'Test' do
    pods
end
```

Please help me.How to solve this issue?

Comment: whats your platform :ios in pod file

Comment: Did you try to do pod update?